# Tikz: Block diagram with summation block having crossed lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I want to draw the block diagram as shown in the below figure.
[image]

I have made the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
 \tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm]
 \tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
 \tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
  \tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\tikzset{
charge node/.style={inner sep=0pt},
pics/sum block/.style n args={4}{
    code={
        \path node (n) [draw, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=9mm] {}
        (n.north) +(0,-1.5mm) node [charge node] {$#1$}
        (n.south) +(0,1.5mm) node [charge node] {$#2$}
        (n.west) +(1.5mm,0) node [charge node] {$#3$}
        (n.east) +(-1.5mm,0) node [charge node] {$#4$}
        ;
        \draw
        (n.north west) -- (n.south east)
        (n.south west) -- (n.north east)
        ;
    }
      }
    }
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\path pic at (20mm,0) {sum block={}{-}{+}{}};
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=3cm,>=latex']

\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
\node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {$K_p + \frac{K_i}{s} + K_ds$};
\node [block, right of=controller,
        node distance=4cm] (system) {$G_p(s)$};

\draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$u(s)$} (system);
\node [output, right of=system] (output) {};
%\node [block, below of=u] (measurements) {Measurements};
\coordinate [below of=u] (measurements) {};
  \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node[pos=0.3] {Set point} (sum);
 \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$E(s)$} (controller);
  \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {Output}(output);
    %\draw [->] (y) |- (measurements);
  \draw [-] (y) |- (measurements);
     %\draw [->] (measurements) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} 
    \draw [->] (measurements) -| %node[pos=1.00] {$-$}  
  node [near end] {} (sum);

  %\draw [->] 
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Thee above code  draws two figures: summation block and block diagram. I want to use summation block drawn in first figure in the block diagram made by the second figure. In other words, I want a crossed lines summation block in my block diagram that is drawn from the second figure made by the above code. Please tell me how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extended comment on Zarko's answer, which I write because we had this discussion several times. I make this a community Wiki to make clear that I am not interested in "stealing reputation points". I am, however, interested in providing the OP with something that follows the rules of the pgfmanual. The pgfmanual says on p. 166.

[image]

I have not seen as single case in which it is really needed to use `\pgfextra` to draw a path. In particular, in this case you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,    % changed
                calc, chains,   % new
                positioning,    % new
                quotes          % new
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, 
  node distance = 6mm and 14mm,
    start chain = A going right,
block/.style = {draw,
                minimum height=11mm, minimum width=12mm,
                on chain=A},
  sum/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=9mm,
                append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode}
                       (\LN.north west) edge (\LN.south east)
                            (\LN.south west) edge (\LN.north east)
                    node[left]     at (\LN.center) {$+$}
                    node[below]    at (\LN.center) {$-$}
                                    },
                node contents={},
                on chain=A},
  arr/.style = {-{Triangle[angle=60:2pt 3]}, semithick},
every edge quotes/.style = {font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
\coordinate[on chain=A] (in);                       % A-1
\node [sum];                                        % A-2
\node [block]   {$K_p + \mfrac{K_i}{s} + K_ds$};
\node [block]   {$G_p(s)$};                         
\coordinate[on chain=A] (out);                      % A-5
%
\draw[arr]  (in)    edge ["Set point"]  (A-2)
            (A-2)   edge ["$E(s)$"]     (A-3)
            (A-3)   edge ["$u(s)$"]     (A-4)
            (A-4)   edge ["Output"]     (out)
            ($(A-4.east)!0.5!(out)$) -- ++ (0,-11mm)
                    -| (A-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that using `\pgfextra` for computing something or assigning a macro a value, as done here, is fine. Using it to construct paths or even nodes is not.

Comment: @Zarko `sum/.style` is correct in this code. No `\pgfextra` wrapped around paths. Only around `\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode}`, which is fine, and which what `\pgfextra` is made for.

Comment: @Zarko Yes, that's a nice link, in particular because of Mark's answer.

Comment: @ZarkoThe accepted answer is by the OP. So the fact that this is the accepted answer is not very meaningful IMHO. If anything it shows that you shouldn't use `\pgfextra` for constructing paths.

Answer (score 1):

with `path picture=` you can to node with circle shape add desired lines and signs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,    % changed
                calc, chains,   % new
                positioning,    % new
                quotes          % new
                }
 \newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box} % new
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
  node distance = 6mm and 14mm,
    start chain = A going right,
block/.style = {draw,
                minimum height=11mm, minimum width=12mm,
                on chain=A},
  sgn/.style = {circle, minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, #1},
  sum/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=9mm, inner sep=0pt,
                path picture={    
                    \draw   (\ppbb.north west) -- (\ppbb.south east)
                            (\ppbb.south west) -- (\ppbb.north east);
                    \node[sgn=right] at (\ppbb.west)  {$+$};
                    \node[sgn=above] at (\ppbb.south) {$-$};
                             },
                node contents={},
                on chain=A},
  arr/.style = {-{Triangle[angle=60:2pt 3]}, semithick},
every edge quotes/.style = {font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
\coordinate[on chain=A] (in);                       % A-1
\node [sum];                                        % A-2
\node [block]   {$K_p + \mfrac{K_i}{s} + K_ds$};
\node [block]   {$G_p(s)$};
\coordinate[on chain=A] (out);                      % A-5
%
\draw[arr]  (in)    edge ["Set point"]  (A-2)
            (A-2)   edge ["$E(s)$"]     (A-3)
            (A-3)   edge ["$u(s)$"]     (A-4)
            (A-4)   edge ["Output"]     (out)
            ($(A-4.east)!0.5!(out)$) -- ++ (0,-11mm)
                    -| (A-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using `\pgfextra` for paths is wrong, sorry. It is also not needed here.